# Calling the McAfee virus scan engine

Tags: c#, virus-scanning, mcafee

I have a request from a client to integrate virus scanning into an application using the McAfee Virus Scan which they have on their server. I have done a bit of investigation and found that McScan32.dll is the main scan engine and it exports various functions that look useful. I have also found mentions of a McAfee Scan Engine SDK, but had trouble getting more information about it.

Has anyone used the McAfee Scan Engine SDK, if so where did you get information about it. I am trying to integrate into a C# application and the SDK appears to export C style functions, but that is a different issue once I get hold of the SDK.

Comment: Wouldn't there be a command line way of accessing it, via an EXE or something? Playing with DLL's might bite you later on in a newer version.

Comment: The do have an official SDK which is used by many people so I think they have solved the version issue. The command line also is only useful for scanning files AFAIK, I want to scan a byte[] in memory. The problem is getting hold of the SDK.

Comment: Have you found the Scan engine SDK?

Comment: Phoenix, after much trawling the best info we could get from McAfee is that their virus scan SDK is discontinued. Having said that, I think if you are willing to shell out the right kind of cash (plenty) they will talk to you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Opswat.com](http://opswat.com) provide a set of API's that wrap around existing virus checker, look at their product Metascan Ultra Plus.