# How to implement file content virus scanner in a JAVA spring core/struts2 based web application?

Tags: java, spring, maven, antivirus, mcafee

I am working on a web application which is accepting some files from external users. Thus, I wish to incorporate one JAVA compatible antivirus in my application which will scan the file content and will generate the outcome whether there is any virus present or not.

I want to manage this feature from my codebase perspective without installing the antivirus on the server itself. My target is to manage some maven dependencies and use some JAVA API for the virus scan which will keep my application server(JBOSS EAP 7.4.3) lightweight.

I have already done some research on this and got few information from some blogs over the internet. But I have not found any dependency related to antivirus API in the maven repository.

Could you please provide some ideas or solutions to solve this problem. Thanks in advance!

Regards,
Ritesh

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3363767/how-do-you-virus-scan-a-file-being-uploaded-to-your-java-webapp-as-it-streams

Answer (score 0):

Mature A/V software supports [ICAP protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Content_Adaptation_Protocol), some examples:

- [Configuring McAfee Web Gateway for ICAP Server](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/api-exchange-gateway/2.2.0/doc/html/GUID-AC8BD890-E522-4BA7-BDA3-2CC455F41C3B.html)
- [KAV ICAP mode](https://support.kaspersky.com/ScanEngine/1.0/en-US/179823.htm)

Quick google search reveals a plenty of ICAP implementations for java (protocol is actually simple), some of them are interesting, for example: [ICAP-avscan](https://github.com/Baekalfen/ICAP-avscan)